# could not find a version that satisfies the requirement symforce>=0.5.0

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04, px4

currently I am trying to get my Flight Controller Unit(FCU) software to run and i am stuck in a situation. I am trying to bash ubuntu.sh in my cloned git folder "PX4-Autopilot" and i ran into an issue where it could not find a version that satisfies the requirement symforce>=0.5.0. I have tried to install symforce with '''pip3 install symforce-sym''' and it was installed, however i still faced the same issue. this is what i received:

Collecting symforce>=0.5.0 (from -r /home/ubuntu/requirements.txt (line 29))
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement symforce>=0.5.0 (from -r /home/ubuntu/requirements.txt (line 29)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for symforce>=0.5.0 (from -r /home/ubuntu/requireme

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem right now, when trying to get a PX4 build system running on a fresh 18.04 VM. It seems they've unintentionally dropped support for a native 18.04 system at this time - symforce is a new requirement, but it needs at least Python 3.8 installed and available, something not available by default on 18.04. You possibly could get it to work on 18.04 with a manual install of a newer Python and using virtual environments in lieu of the system Python (3.6).

I switched to using 20.04 instead, which ships with 3.8, and its been problem-free with the install script and building.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that was unintentional and got fixed by https://github.com/PX4/PX4-Autopilot/pull/20050
You only need Symforce to re-generate some equations for the wind estimator, not to build the code.